# Find all files within directory/sub-directory and group them in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing a script that matches a list of items with an image, which is stored in a folder and possibly sub-folders of this main folder. I want to take all files within the main/sub-folders and put them in an array.

I have a function which finds all files but doesn't lump them in a single array (so that I can easily match the item with image - it is much harder if its multi-dimensional).

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    $images = [];
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
            $images[] = $ff;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($images);
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles("K:\\");
```

Any ideas on how I can do flatten the resultant array?

Comment: To clarify: Instead of printing the HTML of an organized list, you want to produce a PHP array and return the array from the main function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just merge them:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir) {
    $files = glob("$dir/*");
    foreach($files as $f) {
        if(is_dir($f)) {
            $files = array_merge($files, (array)listFolderFiles($f));
        }
    }
    return $files;
}

foreach(listFolderFiles('/path') as $file) {
    echo "<li>$file</li>";
}
```

Edited.  Lots of ways but do it when you call the function maybe.

Comment: This looks good - but I had to edit `php.ini` because it takes longer than 30 seconds. Give me a moment.

Comment: I'm getting another fatal error: `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)`

Comment: My mistake.  Edited the `glob` line.  Might still fail with a huge amount of files.

Comment: I don't follow.  You'll need an example.

Comment: How can I print out `$files`? I added `print_r($files)` before the return statement and I got an array with several keys, the last one being the concatenated list of files - the keys before that had the list of files but were the contents of different files. All I changed was adding `print_r($files)` before the return.

Comment: Edited.  Just do it when calling the function maybe.

Answer (score 0):

To return an array instead of printing the HTML, you will obviously remove the echo commands.

First, define the array at the beginning of the function, such as $return = array();

Now, instead of echoing $ff, you use $return[] = $ff;

Then, instead of just making a recursive call, you want to merge the new array into your current one with array_merge($return, listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff));

Finally, return at the end: return $return;

Comment: Yes - I know you CAN do this easier with a global array, but I am suggesting an array contained within the scope of the function.